# How can I connect from IDEA JProfiler plugin to a JVM started without nowait?

Tags: jprofiler

I'm trying to profile JBoss as follows:

- add `-agentpath:C:\Progra~1\jprofiler8\bin\windows-x64\jprofilerti.dll` to `standalone.bat`. Note that `nowait` is not specified, so the VM will wait for the JProfiler GUI to connect.
- run `standalone.bat`
- attach from IDEA using "Run -> Attach to JVM"

The problem is that the "Quick Attach" window does not see the JBoss JVM, no matter what I do.

Here is the JBoss stdout showing that the JProfiler is ready:

```
Calling "C:\src\ss-master\middle\runtime\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: C:\src\ss-master\middle\runtime\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

  JAVA: C:\tools\java\bin\java

  JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -agentpath:C:\Progra~1\jprofiler8\bin\windows-x64\jprofilerti.dll -Dprogram.name=standalone_jprofiler.bat -Xms256m -Xmx8192m -XX:NewRatio=6 -XX:
PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xss512K -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.war
ning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml -Dorg.jboss.server.bootstrap.maxThreads=8 -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,se
rver=y,suspend=n,address=5001

===============================================================================

JProfiler> Protocol version 41
JProfiler> Using JVMTI
JProfiler> JVMTI version 1.1 detected.
JProfiler> 64-bit library
JProfiler> Listening on port: 8849.
JProfiler> Instrumenting native methods.
JProfiler> Can retransform classes.
JProfiler> Can retransform any class.
JProfiler> Native library initialized
JProfiler> VM initialized
JProfiler> Waiting for a connection from the JProfiler GUI ...
```

Here are some of the things I tried:

- "Quick Attach" from the JProfiler UI also doesn't see the JBoss VM.
- With `nowait` in the startup options, the connection is successful (even from IDEA).
- Without `nowait`, I can only only connect from a pre-defined session in the JProfiler GUI. After this, I can also connect from IDEA.

This last point is the most intriguing. What additional information does the saved session have that enables it to detect a "waiting" JProfiler agent?

Here are the constraints of my use case:

- I want to initiate the profiling from IDEA so that jumping to source code takes me to IDEA.
- I want to profile the startup stage, so I cannot afford adding `nowait`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the profiling agent waits for a connection at startup, the attach mechanism does not work, because the jvmstat system that enables attach has not been loaded yet. In fact, no Java classes have been loaded so nothing that requires Java code can work at that stage.

To profile such a waiting VM, you need a remote profiling session. In JProfiler 8 this is not supported by the IDE integrations.

This will be possible in JProfiler 9.0 (to be released shortly). The attach dialog will have two modes, the local mode that lists all locally running VMs and a a remote attach option where you can enter a host name and a port.

However, you can also profile the JBoss run configuration directly from IDEA. Then you do not have to modify the start script.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Regarding you suggestion, I don't want to run JBoss from the IDE. I need to profile various JBoss installations and it's most convenient to just attach to one of the many instrumented JVMs (as you'd do for debugging).